# windows 7 cmd wait for parallel processes

Tags: windows-7, command-line, python

I am trying to run multiple python scripts parallel in windows 7(and 10).
I am running them all from another python script which performs more functions on the files the scripts are editing.
I want the external script to wait until the other scripts are done running in cmd.

I have tried **start /w** but that made each script wait before closing the cmd window.

essentially what I want to do is for python to wait until the 3 processes are done. the last script is just a *print("done")* and is meaningless for all i care.
this is important for me to solve with 3 processes because i need to do the same thing with 30 (on a server, there are enough available threads)

this is the cmd command I am trying to run.

```
os.system("start python node1.py & start python node2.py & start python node3.py && start /w printstatement.py")
```

any suggestions?

Comment: So, you want to run multiple scripts in parallel, but to wait until all of them are finished? I don't think it is possible with native batch commands. However, you can do it from python, spawn multiple cmds without `start` and attach some listener functions when all of the processes finish executing.

Comment: Yeah i just figured out how to do that. Took a post here for me to actually find the native python answer

Comment: If you've manage to solve your problem natively, you can post an answer here and accept it, or you can delete the question without consequence.

Answer (score 0):

solved with help by using the native python module `subprocess` and with help from the **stachoverflow** community.

```
import subprocess;
procs = [subprocess.Popen(['python', 'node{}.py'.format(n)]) for n in range(1, 4)];
rets = [p.wait() for p in procs]
```

Thank all of you for taking the time.